# href links leading to php if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, href

PHP/HTML Question

I hope this is not a dumb question but I am trying to process data to an if statement from two links. I can do this easily with two form since forms can have submit buttons with names such as:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"> 
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

The if statement in process.php can be if edit do this else do this.

What I want to do is the same thing but from a href links. How would I set up an if statement since a tags can't have names in HTML5?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just check for the presence of a $_GET parameter in process.php?

Comment: Just add it as part of the query string: `a href="process.php?edit=Edit"`. The only difference is that you'll need to look in `$_GET` rather that `$_POST` to see if it's set - though `$_REQUEST` will cover both possibilities.

Comment: So currently I have the link set as process.php?id=$id. I would change it to process.php?id=$id&action=edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g:

```
<a href="process.php?action=edit">Edit</a>

<?php

$action = $_GET['action'];

if($action == 'edit'){
// edit.
}else{
// else another action.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to have the same links for multiple pages with different things to edit/delete? For example: profile.php with edit/delete links to process.php with if statement and then categories.php with edit/delete links to process.php with an if statement. How could you differentiate between the two pages so that you can run different SQL queries dependent upon what page you are coming from?

Comment: you can add another GET variable eg. process.php?site=profile&edit and process.php?site=categories&delete and then ask if($_GET["site"]=="profile"){}...

Answer (score 2):

You could add custom $_GET variables and then evaluate them. For example `example.com/form?action=edit` and `example.com/form?action=delete` and then in PHP:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
if($action === 'edit') {
    this;
} else if ($action === 'delete') {
    that;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly set the form method to `get`, forms will generally send the request as a `post`. You access this data in PHP by calling `$_POST["edit"]`.

A regular link can pass variables in the URL string, like `http://example.com/process.php?edit=true`. You would access these variables by calling `$_GET["edit"]`.

If you want to use the same process.php file for both $_POST and $_GET data you can have the code use the `$_REQUEST` superglobal (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) which combines the data from $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIES

In this case your PHP code would read:

```
if ($_REQUEST["edit"]) {
    /* Some code */
}
elseif ($_REQUEST["delete"]) {
    /* Some other code */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont know if i understand it exactly.
whats about do something like that:

```
<a href="process.php?delete">Delete</a>
<a href="process.php?edit">Edit</a>
```

and then

```
if(defined($_GET["delete"])){
}
else if(defined($_GET["edit"])){
}
```